# Issue Marshaling YAML with an array of struct

Tags: go, yaml, marshalling

I am expecting the resulting yaml file to contain the servers array which are being written as empty objects. How could i go about fixing this so that the servers array is written to the yaml file?

Code:

```
package configwritter

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" //go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2
)

type Server struct {
    name string `yaml:"name"`
    ip   string `yaml:"ip"`
}

type Confugration struct {
    Name    string
    Servers []Server
}

func WriteConfig() {
    config := Confugration{
        Name: "Test",
        Servers: []Server{
            {"server1", "10.0.0.100"},
            {"server1", "10.0.0.101"},
        },
    }

    data, err := yaml.Marshal(&config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err2 := ioutil.WriteFile("config.yaml", data, 0)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    fmt.Println("data written")
}
```

Output:

```
name: Test
servers:
- {}
- {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the fields on your `Server` struct need to be public in order for the `yaml` module to read them.

From the [`Marshal` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal):

> Struct fields are only marshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter)

You can fix this by changing the type definition for `Server` so that the fields are exported (have capitalized names), like so:

```
type Server struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
    IP   string `yaml:"ip"`
}
```

With output `config.yaml` file:

```yaml
name: Test
servers:
- name: server1
  ip: 10.0.0.100
- name: server1
  ip: 10.0.0.101
```

Comment: Generally, @talkersoft, capitalize any field name that is not "internal" to the struct